# List QCheckBox items in Qt layout

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a layout containing only a bunch of checkboxes, and rather than querying the state of every one manually I want to loop over the items in the layout, then simply grab their label if they are active.

```
for i in xrange(self.qt_window.verticalLayout_cb.count()):
    box = self.qt_window.verticalLayout_cb.itemAt(i)
    print box
```

The problem here is that it's returning them as QWidgetItem, not QCheckBox so I can't work with them. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way?

Comment: are you using listwidget??

Answer (score 0):

The ownership of the checkboxes in a layout is transferred to the widget which contains the layout.

So you can check from there:

```
for x in widget.children():
    if isinstance(x, QCheckBox):
        if x.isChecked():
            print x.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `QWidgetItem` like this:

```
for i in xrange(self.qt_window.verticalLayout_cb.count()):
    item = self.qt_window.verticalLayout_cb.itemAt(i)
    widget = item.widget()
    if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QCheckBox):
        print(widget.text())
```

Note that `itemAt()` can return a `QLayout`, a `QSpacerItem` or a `QWidgetItem`. These all have a `widget()` method (because they all inherit [`QLayoutItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html#QLayoutItem)), but it is not safe to assume a widget will always be returned. A spacer-item doesn't contain a widget, for instance, so it would just return `None`.